# How to display the users location (country) back to them, on a website?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm looking for a way to get a message on my site that says: *We ship to [Users country location]!*

So I would need to retrieve the users Country location, without them having to accept any localization plugin or whatnot. Users using a proxy or whatnot will be extremely rare, so I don't worry too much about them. A default message may be (if no location can be found for whatever reason) *We ship worldwide!* or something similar.

Is there any easy way to go about this? My PHP and Javascript skills are very limited. I could find some documentation on retrieving a country name, but not on displaying it back to the customer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: With [HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like Maxmind Geolite2 free database:

http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/

It is updated on the first Tuesday of each month and it is distributed under the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License.

There are a lot of API to use with this database, take a look here: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/downloadable/#MaxMind_APIs

Comment: link only answers are discouraged